# Using the find command with a shell variable is not working (No such file or directory)

Tags: variables, find, zsh, expansion

The find commands works with a specified string but fails (No such file or directory) when a create a shell variable - see below. I tried a number of combinations and permutations using the escape (\) character with not luck.

```
$ zsh --version                                                                                            
zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)

$ sw_vers -productVersion                                                                                         
10.15.2

$ #
$ # The following FIND command works as expected.
$ #
$ find /Volumes/SeagateDrive/Backups.backupdb/Donald\'s\ iMac/*/Macintosh\ HD\ -\ Data/Users/Jazzfess1/ 

$ #
$ # I create a variable to use instead of the above string.
$ #
export bck="/Volumes/SeagateDrive/Backups.backupdb/Donald\'s\ iMac/*/Macintosh\ HD\ -\ Data/Users/Jazzfess1/“
$ echo $bck
/Volumes/SeagateDrive/Backups.backupdb/Donald\'s\ iMac/*/Macintosh\ HD\ -\ Data/Users/Jazzfess1/

$ #

$ # The variable is not working: without or with quotes
$ #
$ find $bck
find: /Volumes/SeagateDrive/Backups.backupdb/Donald\'s\ iMac/*/Macintosh\ HD\ -\ Data/Users/Jazzfess1/: No such file or directory

$ find “$bck”
find: /Volumes/SeagateDrive/Backups.backupdb/Donald\'s\ iMac/*/Macintosh\ HD\ -\ Data/Users/Jazzfess1/: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

zsh doesn't allow the use of globbing in variables by default, you have to request it explicitly:

```
find $~bck
```

P.S.
And you don't have to escape spaces and single quotes in double ones:

```
export bck="/Volumes/SeagateDrive/Backups.backupdb/Donald's iMac/*/Macintosh HD - Data/Users/Jazzfess1/"
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but this tip did not work for me - I still get the "No such file or directory” error.

Comment: Never mind. This does in fact work - sorry for the false alarm!

Answer (score 1):

You are escaping too many things in your assignment to `bck`. (It also doesn't need to be exported.)

```
bck="/Volumes/SeagateDrive/Backups.backupdb/Donald's iMac/*/Macintosh HD - Data/Users/Jazzfess1/"
```

Without double quotes, you would escape the single quotes and the spaces (as demonstrated below).

Also, when you *expand* `bck`, the `*` will be treated literally, not as a glob for the shell to expand further. Modify your `find` command to read

```
bck=/Volumes/SeagateDrive/Backups.backupdb/Donald\'s\ iMac/
find "$bck" -name "Macintosh HD - Data/Users/Jazzfess1" -type d
```

(This is a more `bash`-centric answer, though. While it should work in `zsh` as well, vonschlager's suggestion to use `$~bck` is simpler for `zsh`.)